# Content extraction and persistence using Pandoc & Lenses

Tags: html, parsing, haskell, json

Endpoints to save a Pandoc document to the database using persistent. Prior to being stored, the code strips out all of the paragraph content (the `[Inline]`'s) and stores these using the type `Stream`. Each extraction is marked with the relevant `Stream` id in the Pandoc document (ie `<span data-stream-id="3"/>` in HTML).

When it comes to reading, the action expands the document adding in each stream with it's corresponding ID, so content is re-injected back into the document. Another piece of functionality the read action provides is pagination, so `/read/:id/5` reads the 5th block out of the `[Block]`'s that make up the document.

Relevant types:

```
DocumentListing
    position Int
    lastAccessed UTCTime Maybe
    belongs AccountId
    document DocumentId
    deriving Eq Show
Document
    title String
    body String
    created UTCTime Maybe
    deriving Eq Show
Stream
    content String
    deriving Eq Show
```

Persistent function to save document to DB when uploaded:

```
data ExtractedStream =
  ExtractedStream
    { unStreamId :: String
    , unStreamElements :: [Block]
    }

createDocument :: MonadIO m => String -> Pandoc -> Key Account -> SqlPersistT m (Key Document)
createDocument title pandoc owner = do
  now <- liftIO getCurrentTime
  extractedPandoc <- extractStreams pandoc
  key_ <- insert $ Document title (writeHtmlString def extractedPandoc) (Just now)
  _ <- insert $ DocumentListing 0 Nothing owner key_
  pure key_

extractStreams :: MonadIO m => Pandoc -> SqlPersistT m Pandoc
extractStreams = mapMOf (body . each . _Para) f
  where
    f :: MonadIO m => [Inline] -> SqlPersistT m [Inline]
    f els = do
      streamId <- insert . Stream . writeHtmlString def . wrapPlain $ els
      pure [ createStreamElement streamId ]

createStreamElement :: Key Stream -> Inline
createStreamElement streamId = Span ("", [], [("stream-id", show . fromSqlKey $ streamId)]) []

wrapPlain :: [Inline] -> Pandoc
wrapPlain = Pandoc nullMeta . (: []) . Plain

unwrapPlain :: Pandoc -> [Inline]
unwrapPlain = toListOf (each . blockInlines) . view body
```

Api action:

```
data PagedDocument = PagedDocument Int [Block]

instance ToJSON PagedDocument where
  toJSON (PagedDocument page blocks) = object
    [ "blocks" .= blocks
    , "page" .= page
    ]

show :: Config -> AuthResult (Key Account) -> Int64 -> Int -> Handler PagedDocument
show config auth docId page =
  case auth of
    Authenticated acc ->
      maybe (throw404 "Document not found") pure =<<
        runSqlPool (getPagedDocument acc docId page) (getPool config)
    _ ->
      throwAll err401

getPagedDocument :: MonadIO m => Key Account -> Int64 -> Int -> SqlPersistT m (Maybe PagedDocument)
getPagedDocument acc docId page = do
  _ <- Queries.updateDocumentPosition docId acc page
  mDoc <- getDocument docId
  mapM injectStreams (getPage page =<< mDoc)

getPage :: Int -> Document -> Maybe PagedDocument
getPage page (Document _ body _) =
  either (const Nothing) Just $ createPagedDocument . unPandocBody <$> readHtml def body
  where
    createPagedDocument pages = PagedDocument page' . take 1 . drop page' $ pages
      where page' = max 0 . min (length pages - 1) $ page

unPandocBody :: Pandoc -> [Block]
unPandocBody (Pandoc _ body) = body

injectStreams :: MonadIO m => PagedDocument -> SqlPersistT m PagedDocument
injectStreams (PagedDocument num content) = do
  injected <- mapMOf (each . blockInlines) extractStream content
  pure $ PagedDocument num injected
  where
    extractStream :: MonadIO m => Inline -> SqlPersistT m Inline
    extractStream el =
      case getStreamId el of
          Just sid -> do
            x <- get . toSqlKey $ sid
            pure . M.fromMaybe invalidStream $ streamToInline =<< x
          Nothing -> pure streamNotFound

streamToInline :: Stream -> Maybe Inline
streamToInline (Stream content) =
  eitherToMaybe $ Span ("sentence", [], []) . unwrapPlain <$> readHtml def content

eitherToMaybe :: Either b a -> Maybe a
eitherToMaybe = either (const Nothing) Just

streamNotFound :: Inline
streamNotFound = Span nullAttr [ Str "<Stream not found>" ]

invalidStream :: Inline
invalidStream = Span nullAttr [ Str "<Invalid stream>" ]

getStreamId :: Inline -> Maybe Int64
getStreamId = \case
  Span (_, _, attr) _ -> Json.parse . snd =<< find ((==) "stream-id" . fst) attr
  _ -> Nothing

find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
find f = M.listToMaybe . filter f
```

Json helper:

```
import           Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy               as LT
import           Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding

parse :: (FromJSON a) => String -> Maybe a
parse = decode . encodeUtf8 . LT.pack

stringify :: (ToJSON a) => a -> String
stringify = LT.unpack . decodeUtf8 . encode
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the definition for `PagedDocument`, and your first code paragraph doesn't look like Haskell to me.

You have one more place where you could use your `eitherToMaybe`. Both uses are for `readHtml`, so you could instead wrap `readHtml` in your name for it which returns a `Maybe`.

Assuming a `_content` lens into the content field of `PagedDocument`:

`injectStreams = mapMOf (_content . each . blockInlines) extractStream` (note that `mapMOf = id`)

The source of https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-lens-0.6.2/docs/Text-Pandoc-Lens.html#t:HasAttr seems to want to give you the attributes in `Code` `Inline`s too. Maybe they have reason for this - should you also retrieve that in `streamToId`? If so:

`getStreamId = Json.parse <=< preview (attributes . _3 . traverse . itraversed . index "stream-id")`

In general, I think everything that's used only once should be inlined - for example `injectStreams` like:

`forMOf (_Just . _content . each . blockInlines) (getPage page =<< mDoc) extractStream`

Comment: Updated the question to include the `PagedDocument` definition. The types at the top are persistent types using template haskell, but they evaluate to haskell data types, ie the one for `Stream` becomes:

    `data Stream = Stream
        { streamContent :: String
        } deriving (Eq, Show)`

for example...